# Pedir n entradas em python

Tags: python, loop

Estou com dificuldade nesse exercício:

"Faça um programa que peça para n pessoas a sua idade, ao final o programa deverá verificar se a média de idade da turma varia entre 0 e 25, 26 e 60 e maior que 60; e então, dizer se a turma é “jovem”, “adulta” ou “idosa”, conforme a média calculada. O programa deve finalizar quando for digitado -1."

Eu não sei como pedir a idade de n pessoas. Como eu faria isso ?

Comment: Com a função `input` é uma forma simples.

Answer (score 3):

> Eu não sei como pedir a idade de n pessoas. Como eu faria isso ?

```
idade = 0
lista_com_idades = []
while idade != '-1':
    idade = input('Diga sua idade: ')
    lista_com_idades.append(idade)
```

Essa é a reposta para sua pergunta. Enquanto o usuário não digita '-1' ele continua perguntando a idade.
Espero ter ajudado !

Comment: Achei ruim o fato de a idade `-1` ficar armazenada

Answer (score 2):

Em Python 3.
Não sei se entendi a dúvida. Mas o seguinte funciona:

```
z=0
x=[]
while z != -1:
    z = int(input('Digite a idade: '))

    if z != -1:
        x.append(z)

if len(x) != 0:
    media = sum(x)/len(x)

m = round(media,0)

if 0 <= m <= 25:
    print('Populacao jovem')

if 26 <= m <= 60:
    print('Populacao adulta')

if m > 60:
    print('Populacao idosa')
```

Seria isso?

EDIT: erro no round, deve ser 0, não 1. Tbm inclui m "if" para verificar se teve alguma idade digitada.

Comment: É isso mesmo, ainda to aprendendo a programar, e n tinha conhecimento desse x.append.
Valeu !

Comment: Você poderia ter usado a divisão inteira `sum(x)//len(x)` para evitar arredondar

Comment: O problema de usar sum(x)//len(x) é que sempre arredonda para baixo, como em int(), trunca o número em vez de arredondar. Certo? (sou novato em programação)

Answer (score -1):

Pode fazer um ciclo em um range de dados pelo utilizador:

```
n = raw_input("Quantas pessoas são?")
for i in range(1,n):
blabla
```

Comment: Aí que tá, eu n posso fazer um ciclo dado pelo utilizador, quem vai processar o código é o run codes.
A entrada de dados deve parar quando digitar "-1".

Comment: então faz um while,

Comment: Você está lendo `n-1` dados. E também é Python 2 esse `raw_input` na minha lembrança